# Safari UI freezes on getUserMedia until promise is returned

Tags: safari, webrtc, getusermedia

When calling getUserMedia on Safari (V 17.0) on MacOS 13.6 Safari UI freezes until the promise is resolved.  It appears that user interactions are still happening, but nothing is displayed until getUserMedia resolves or rejects.  A quick test to show the behavior can be done by running the following html from a local file.  Click on the getUserMedia button then try to increase the counter.  Nothing happens until the promise is resolved, but every click will be counted.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick=add()>Increase Counter</button>
    <p id="counter">0</p>
    <button onclick=gum()>getUserMedia</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0
        function add() {
          counter ++
          document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter
        }
        async function gum() {
          await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:true})
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This makes for a bad user experience while doing things like collecting device names etc that should be able to happen in the background.  Any work around to this?  Or is this just a bug in how Safari runs getUserMedia?

Comment: The UI is not frozen but the overlay won't allow you to click a button or interact with the actual page while the Safari getUserMedia dialog is open? At least that is how it behaves on iOS

Comment: What I'm seeing is after the permissions dialog is closed, the UI is frozen.  The odd thing is clicking the button still works (either without UI updates or is cached), but the display is not updated until getUserMedia is finished.  I tested this with the counter update function in the above dummy code and the counted number increases however many times I hit the button, but only renders after gum completes.  I haven't checked if iOS has the same behavior as MacOS where I noticed this.